# Can I switch religions to that of a conquered opponent?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I'm playing America/Hinduism, and just conquered Ethiopia/Christianity, but the strength of the Christianity has taken over all of my cities.  All I can do with religion is build Pagodas and great people.

Questions:

- Do I get any benefits from a conquered opponent's religion?
- If no, is there a way to 'switch' my state religion to that of a conquered
  opponent?
- Is there a way to completely kill off a conquered opponent's religion?  I tried sending an Inquisitor to the capital, but the religions pressure did not change and within three turns that city was its original religion again.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97282/eradicate-a-religion

Comment: Also related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94291/do-your-opponents-gain-the-benefit-of-a-religion-you-found?rq=1 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149957/if-you-conquer-a-holy-city-do-you-take-ownership-of-that-religion?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The only benefits you receive from a religion founded by another civilization are the benefits from the Follower Beliefs in each city that has the religion, which affect the city directly rather than the owner of the religion.
- There is no way to change your state religion, nor to adopt one of an opponent if you didn't already have one. You're stuck with either the one you found yourself, or none at all.
- While it is possible to overwhelm an opposing religion such that it's not the majority religion in any city, that religion's Holy City will always exert pressure for its religion, meaning it can never be fully removed from the game. Further, a Holy City can never be razed. If your religion is strong enough, you might be able to keep the rival Holy City locked down, but it could be difficult.

Comment: The best I've been able to do is remove the opponent's religion from all but the holy city which is always the capital. One of the Piety Social Policies grants cities the pantheon belief of the second-most popular religion in that city—if there is one. You will then want to spread the captured religion to your other cities that can make use of its pantheon belief.

Comment: I've been able to wipe out an opposing religion, but to do it, I had to convert all the surrounding cities as well as the holy city, _and_ use an inquisitor on the holy city.  My experience is that while use of an inquisitor stops the holy city from coming back on its own, pressure from nearby cities can "revive" it, so you have to take care of those first.

Comment: Got it thanks.  So the first bullet point means I get at least some benefit out of the deal, so it all depends on the Follower Beliefs.  Thanks.  -Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "switch" your religions, in the sense of taking ownership of the religion.  You only get the founder/enhancer beliefs of a religion that you created or enhanced.  You do however get the follower beliefs of a religion your city follows.  As you pointed out, you can buy pagodas.  Sometimes I deliberately let a rival religion exist in my cities long enough to buy their unique buildings, and only then do I remove it.

It is possible to remove a holy city, but you have to basically hit it with a combo.
First, use inquisitors to remove it from any friendly cities following it.  If any city states have it, you'll probably have to use a prophet.
Then, once there's no cities providing pressure from that religion, use an inquisitor on their holy city and then hit it with a prophet.